# How to create a new column type with top alignment

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, columns

I am trying to create a table which has wrapped text and the text in each cell is ragged right and top aligned.  As you can see in the following image I'm not getting the top alignment.

[image: Text is not aligned at the top of each cell]

Here is my LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}    \vspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}[!t]
        \centering
    \begin{tabular}[t]{|L{1.8cm}| L{2.3cm}|}
        \hline
        This is a long line.  It sets the height of the column and is top aligned &i want this to be top aligned too\\\hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

I would appreciate any hints for how to fix this.

Thank you!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Replacing `m{#1}` with `p{#1}` doesn't work?

Comment: @JaneCH Remove the `\hspace{0pt}\vspace{0pt}` bits.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the suggestion.  Actually I was playing around with the \vspace{1pt} as I wanted to put a little space at the top, but it seems to insert the space under the first line of text in the cell, instead of above the first line.  My table looks a bit cramped without any space there.  Do you know how to force a space above the first line of text in each cell?

Comment: @JaneCH Use the rule commands provided by the `booktabs` package and no vertical rule.

Answer (score 7):

[ **Just to answer the unanswered, converting the comment into an answer** ]

Replace `m{#1}` with `p{#1}`

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}[!t]
        \centering
    \begin{tabular}[t]{|L{1.8cm}|L{2.3cm}|}
        \hline
        This is a long line. It sets the height of the column and is top aligned & I want this to be top aligned too\\\hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that I've removed the spurious `\hspace{0pt}    \vspace{0pt}` from your code.